# Serving java 1.8 source in jar for JWS as static file

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've put a .jar file of source 1.8 as as static file for the client to launch via JWS. However, when i try to update my app, i receive the following error:

Unable to update app: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: path-to-my-jar

Which seems to indicate that gae is recognizing the classes in my jar as servlets, which can only be written in Java 7, however they aren't and i don't intend to run them as servlets.

My appengine-web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>projectid</application>
<version>0.1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<static-files>
    <include path="/**.jnlp"/>
    <include path="/**.jar"/>
</static-files>
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Not really, i'm not trying to run Java 8 servlets, just store a Java 8 jar as static file, like an image or whatever, so GAE shouldn't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/admin/Application.java) there is no way to switch off the check for the Java version - even if you just want to serve the JAR file and not execute it. I believe the check was introduced with App Engine SDK version 1.9.25. I reverted back to App Engine SDK 1.9.24 and was able to deploy again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to help you because I found an error is almost like you. About "Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7"

> In case of me as I use Eclipse to deploy my app engine project, I set
>   the properties of project.

1. Java compiler: set to 1.7 version.
2. Project facet: set to 1.7 too.

It solves my problem.
Hope to help you.

Comment: That is not the case with me, the project is set to 1.7 source, but it has additional, static jar files with source 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change -vm argument in eclipse.ini file to the bin folder of your JRE7 and check 1.7 as java-compiler which referred at:
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/jdk_compliance

Answer (score 0):

This section in the [Static files and resource files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?csw=1#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files) doc suggests GAE has some default logic to treat files in dual mode, which could be related to the behaviour you're seeing:

> By default, all files in the WAR are treated as both static files and
>   resource files, except for JSP files, which are compiled into servlet
>   classes and mapped to URL paths, and files in the WEB-INF/ directory,
>   which are never served as static files and always available to the app
>   as resource files.

Your `appengine-web.xml` has a `static-files` section, but doesn't have a `resource-files` one, which could make all files (including your `.jar` file) be treated as resources as well and thus being subjected to GAE's version check.

Based on this supposition I'd try adding a `resource-files` section, eventually with an explicit exclusion rule for that `.jar` file.

I'm mostly speculating, tho...

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I added <exclude path="/**.jar" /> under a new resource-files tag and i'm still getting the same error.